# how do i set up this endpoint to correctly get a firebase document

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, vercel

How do I use the information and pass it to the backend to retrieve something from the database?

code in site:

```
 {Object.values(data)?.map((input) => (
      <button
        onClick={() => {
      axios.get('/api/user', input).then(function (response) {
        alert(response.reading);
      });


    }}
  >
    {input}
  </button>
))}
```

code in node

```
import { db } from '../../lib/firebase';

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  let store = {};

  console.log(req.body, 'hello');
  const user = await db.collection('readings').doc(req.body).get();
  if (!user.exists) {
    return res.status(404).json({});
  }

  return res.status(404).json({ id: user.id, ...user.data() });
```

Comment: What is the information that you need to pass in this case?

Comment: i need to pass the input from the map.

it is a button that you click and it sends the information on the button to the backend

Comment: In general, you don't attach `bodies` to a GET request. You certainly *can*, but it isn't useful. If you need to pass info to your GET endpoint, do it via the URL.

Comment: so should I use a post request? how would I go about doing this? does a post still give me information?

Comment: What is the input? Is it just a string or something? can you log and share it? All you need to do is pass document ID as in the provided code. That can be done by query params

Comment: the input is a string, it is taken from the button on the frontend.

pass the document id?

doc(req.body).

I'm using post request and it seems to almost work.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP methods have a meaning, and it is usually very straightforward:

- GET requests are meant to GET something from the server (back-end)
- POST requests are meant to POST something to the server (back-end)
- ...

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/5467710) for more information about GET request, and more broadly, the [HTTP 1.1 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616).

Starting from there, the question you need to ask yourself is:

> What do I want to do with the server? Get something from it? Post something for it to save it to the database? Delete a record from the db?

Seeing your back-end code, it seems you want to GET (retrieve) something from the server and send it back to the front-end.

One of the way to do it is with URL parameters. Your URL could look something like this: `http://localhost:3000/api/users?first_name=Alexander&last_name=Hemming`

From that, on the server side:

```
import { db } from '../../lib/firebase';

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  let store = {};
  //depending on what framework you use to route, this could differ
  const {params} = req;

  // should display an object with first_name and last_name as keys
  console.log(params);
  const user = await db.collection('readings').doc(params).get();
  if (!user.exists) {
    return res.status(404).json({});
  }

  return res.status(404).json({ id: user.id, ...user.data() });
```

Comment: doing this:
       {Object.values(data)?.map((input) => (
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              axios
                .get(`/api/user?account=${input}`)
                .then(function (response) {
                  console.log('sssssssssssssss');
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                  console.log(error);
                });
            }}
          >
            {input}
          </button>
        ))}

the console.log does not fire